# TypeError: Cannot read property 'count.' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

```
componentDidMount(props) {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (props.count !== 0) {
            this.stateHandler()
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

i have a problem with the interval, the console give me the next error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined.
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

componentDidMount does not receive `props` in arguments. Try checking props as below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.props.count !== 0) {
            this.stateHandler()
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: you don't need to pass props to `componentdidmount`. Just call it inside there as `this.props.count`